# GnuParallel: Parallelizing a script over a cluster, script writes files to the Master node

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a simple bash script which takes as input a list of directory names in a text file. It traverses these directories one by one, copies the output of `pwd` to a file, and moves this file to a results directory. I can parallelize this script on my 4 core machine using Gnuparallel easily. The bash script (`myScript.sh`) is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash

par_func (){
    name=$1
    cd /home/zahaib/parentFolder/$name
    pwd > $name.txt
    mv $name.txt /home/zahaib/result/
    cd /home/zahaib/parentFolder
    }

export -f par_func
parallel -a /home/zahaib/folderList.txt -j 10 par_func
```

Now I want to parallelize the same script on a Cluster, all the worker nodes have mounted the home directory of the Master node so I can see the output of `ls /home/zahaib/` on all worker nodes.

I tried using the `--env` to export the `par_func`. I also have a list of worker nodes in a `workerList.txt` file. My initial idea was to invoke `parallel` by changing the last line in my script above with the following:

```
parallel -vv --env par_func --slf /home/zahaib/workerList.txt -a /home/zahaib/folderList.txt -j 10 par_func
```

However, this does not seem to work and the shell on Master node just hangs after I do `./myScript.sh`. What am I missing here?

The contents of my folderList.txt are as follows:

```
docs
dnload
driver
pics
music
.
.
```

and the contents of my workerList.txt are as follows:

```
2//usr/bin/ssh zahaib@node-1
2//usr/bin/ssh zahaib@node-2
2//usr/bin/ssh zahaib@node-3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description you are doing the right thing, so you may have hit a bug.

Try minimizing workerList.txt and folderList.txt and then run:

```
parallel -D ...
```

(And also checkout the option --result which might be useful to you).

Comment: yeah the problem seems to have been because of a machine that was down which was causing the shell to hang. I think `parallel` was trying to dispatch a job to that machine since it was there in workerList.txt. Removing it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: To check if machines are down use '--filter-hosts'